# Add location marker on plotted Geopandas Dataframe using Folium

Tags: geopandas, folium

## Context

I have an merged geodataframe of 1). Postalcode areas and 2). total amount of deliveries within that postalcode area in the city of Groningen called `results`. The geodataframe includes geometry that include Polygons and Multiploygons visualizing different Postal code areas within the city.

[image: result geopandas.geodataframe]

I am new to GeoPandas and therefore I've tried different tutorials including [this one](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/interactive_mapping.html) from the geopandas official website wherein I got introduced into interactive Folium maps, which I really like. I was able to plot my geodataframe using `result.explore()`, which resulted in the following map

[image]

### The problem

So far so good, but now I want to simply place an marker using the folium libarty with the goal to calculate the distance between the marker and the postalcode areas. After some looking on the internet I found out in the [quickstart guild](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html) that you need to create an `folium.Map`, then you need `folium.Choropleth` for my geodataframe and `folium.Marker` and add them to the `folium.Map`.

```
m = folium.Map(location=[53.21917, 6.56667], zoom_start=15)

folium.Marker(
    [53.210903, 6.598276], 
    popup="My marker"
).add_to(m)

folium.Choropleth(results, data=results, columns="Postcode", fill_color='OrRd', name="Postalcode areas").add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

But when try to run the above code I get the following error:

[image]

### What is the (possible) best way?

Besides my failing code (which would be great if someone could help me out). I am curious if this is the way to do it (Folium map + marker + choropleth). Is it not possible to call `geodataframe.explore()` which results into the map in second picture and then just add an marker on the same map? I have the feeling that I am making it too difficult, there must be an better solution using Geopandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you have not provided the geometry.  Have found postal districts of Netherlands and used that
- `explore()` supports will draw a point as a marker with appropriate parameters
- hence two layers,

  - one is postal areas coloured using number of deliveries
  - second is point, with distance to each area calculated

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

geo_url = "https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/cbsgebiedsindelingen/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=2.0.0&typeName=cbs_provincie_2017_gegeneraliseerd&outputFormat=json"

gdf = gpd.read_file(geo_url).assign(
    deliveries=lambda d: np.random.randint(10**4, 10**6, len(d))
)

p = gpd.GeoSeries(shapely.geometry.Point(6.598276, 53.210903), crs="epsg:4386")

# calc distances to point
gdf["distance"] = gdf.distance(p.to_crs(gdf.crs).values[0])

# dataframe of flattened distances
dfp = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        "<br>".join(
            [f"{a} - {b:.2f}" for a, b in gdf.loc[:, ["statcode", "distance"]].values]
        )
    ],
    columns=["info"],
)

# generate colored choropleth
m = gdf.explore(
    column="deliveries", categorical=True, legend=False, height=400, width=400
)
# add marker with distances
gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=p,
    data=dfp,
).explore(m=m, marker_type="marker")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution and +1 for the geo_url!

Comment: Wonderful! I didn't know about gdf.explore(m=m) which essentially combines two folium map instances together. Sweet!